# iOS UITableView is not selectable when it is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing this issue and I am not getting any clear answer. I have a `UITableView` which works fine when it loads for the first time but when it scrolls, it is not selectable, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never gets a call. Also I've button in my cell, it's not clickable either. But I can still scroll tableview. This is my code :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : ContactTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell") as! ContactTableViewCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.delegate = self

        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorsArray!.count)))

        if(!shouldUseFilteredResults) {

            cell.setFilteredContents(_with: addressBookArray![indexPath.row], theme: themeStyle!, randomColor: colorsArray![randomNumber])
        }
        else {

            cell.setFilteredContents(_with: filteredAddressBook[indexPath.row], theme: themeStyle!, randomColor: colorsArray![randomNumber])

            cell.contactNameLabel.attributedText = self.highlightSearchResult(resultString: cell.contactNameLabel.text!)
        }


        return cell
    }
```

In cell :

```
public func setFilteredContents (_with contact : [String : Any], theme : Theme, randomColor : UIColor)
    {
        contactDictionary = contact;

        contactNameLabel.text = String(describing: contact["FullName"]!)

        self.setTheme(theme: theme, randomColor: randomColor)

        if (contact["ImageDataString"] != nil)
        {
            let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: contact["ImageDataString"] as! String)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: thumbnailView.bounds)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(imageView.height()/2)
            imageView.image = image
            thumbnailView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
        else {

            self.setThumbnail(fullName: contactNameLabel.text!)
        }
    }

 private func setThumbnail(fullName : String)
    {
        let vibrancy = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        let backgroundView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancy)
        backgroundView.frame = thumbnailView.bounds
        thumbnailView.addSubview(backgroundView)

        let thumbNailLabel = UILabel(frame: thumbnailView.bounds)
        thumbNailLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        thumbNailLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        thumbNailLabel.textAlignment = .center

        var initialLettersString = String()
        let wordsArray = fullName.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespaces)

        for word in wordsArray
        {
            if(word != "")
            {
                initialLettersString.append(String(describing: word.characters.first!))
            }
        }

        if(initialLettersString.characters.count == 1)
        {
            initialLettersString =  String(initialLettersString[..<initialLettersString.index(initialLettersString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]).uppercased()
        }
        if(initialLettersString.characters.count > 1)
        {
            initialLettersString = String(initialLettersString[..<initialLettersString.index(initialLettersString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)]).uppercased()
        }

        thumbNailLabel.text = initialLettersString as String

        backgroundView.contentView.addSubview(thumbNailLabel)
    }



private func setTheme(theme : Theme, randomColor : UIColor)
    {
        let isContactFavorite = contactDictionary?[Constants.TTCIsContactFavoriteKey] as? Bool

        thumbnailView.backgroundColor = randomColor

        if(theme == Theme.Light)
        {
            contactNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            if(!isContactFavorite!)
            {
                favoritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_dark.png"), for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                favoritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite.png"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
        else if(theme == Theme.Dark)
        {
            contactNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

            if(!isContactFavorite!)
            {
                favoritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_white.png"), for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                favoritesButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite.png"), for: .normal)
            }
        }

        for view in thumbnailView.subviews
        {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Custom Cell :
[image: Custom Cell]

What could be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by not selectable? No selected look or didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called?

Comment: sorry my bad, didSelectRowAtIndexPath not get called

Comment: Did you Set the delegate and datasource of your tableview properly in viewdidload or elsewhere? Just confirming.

Comment: @Tuhin I've set those in Storyboard and Since TableView is selectable first time so it shouldn't be the issue

Comment: I don't trust StoryBoard in this case. Please set it in viewdidload by using the outlet once and let see. Also make sure you/system accidentally removing any of the allocation of your tableview while scrolling.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, also no allocation of tableview was removed

Comment: Button in my cell isn't clickable either after scroll

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Comment: @chengsam what else do you need?

Comment: @chengsam Added more code

Comment: Okay fine! It would be very helpful if you add some exact screenshot of the cell with your question.

Comment: @Tuhin added a screenshot

Comment: Which one is the button? Finally where did you wrote IBAction method for that button?

Comment: @Tuhin Star is a Button, and its IBAction is in the Cell

Comment: Move this conversation over chat!

Comment: @Tuhin I’m okay with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156157/discussion-between-thewarri0r9-and-tuhin).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right.

Just check your button frame does lies inside your cell.

Some times your cell height is less and button is outside the bounds of cell.

Comment: cell.delegate = self in viewDidLoad()?

Answer (score 0):

This may also because of overriding default touch events with `UITapRecognizer`s in the View Hierarchy
Remove any `tap recognizer`s set to to `UITableview` `Parent View`

Comment: I tried removing all tap recognizers but let me try it again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. Issue was with `SwipeCellKit` which I was using for CustomCell. Removing it solved it!